# How do I invoke a function using dlsym() where I know the number of arguments but not the type and neither the return type of the function?

Tags: c, dlopen, dlsym

I am trying to create a generic tool using dlsym and dlopen with the intention of loading an external library and calling a particular function from it. My current code for the tool is:

```
void bootload(string libraryname, string functionname, int argc, char** argv) {
    void *handle;
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen(libraryname.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        cout << "\nSuccessfuly opened " << libraryname << endl;
    }

    dlerror();

    typedef void (*bootload_t)();
    bootload_t bl_function = (bootload_t) dlsym(handle, functionname.c_str());

    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bl_function();
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

Now argc and argv will contain the number and instances of the arguments respectively of the function functionname.

How do I call functionname correctly by passing the right arguments and returning the right type?

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to parse debug information (using `libdwarf`, for example), to find out function declaration. But how it can help you? Write a big `if`/`else` for all possible combinations of parameters? Or manually prepare the stack before calling the function?

Comment: You cannot. You need to know the types.

Comment: It looks like you want to use [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/). Naturally you still need to know (in runtime) the type of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks rodrigo. Yes libffi solved the return type problem and I passed in the types for all the arguments through a json config file.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I invoke a function using dlsym() where I know the number of arguments but not the type and neither the return type of the function?

You don't. It's *not possible* to pass parameters the function expects if you don't know their types.